# Why did God instituted the Sacrificial system if prayers can atone for sins?

Tags: korban, kaparah-atonement

I have often seen Jews saying that prayers and repentance are sufficient for atonement, then why was the animal sacrificial system was started to begin with, and who are the Rabbis responsible for the view that prayers **replaced** the sacrificial system? The view that prayers substitutes and replaces the blood sacrificial implies that it is an alternate, contradictory way of atonement than the sacrificial system. Can you also explain when this view began?

Answer (score 1):

1. The sin offering is for unintentional sins
2. When a person repents and brings an animal that is his possession he is expressing that he has "Sacrificed" something of value as a reminder that he should not repeat his sins.
3. According to King Solomon the sacrifice of a wicked person is an abomination to G-d. so  important thing for forgiveness of sins is repentance, living by the Law's of G-d and doing good.
4. If a person could not afford an animal he could bring flour and oil.(No blood needed)

All these points are in the Torah.

Below is one of the many verses where G-d says clearly he needs us to repent and does not need blood to be offered to him.

**Isaiah 1:11** Of what use are your many sacrifices to Me? says the Lord. I am sated with the burnt-offerings of rams and the fat of fattened cattle; and the blood of bulls and sheep and he goats I do not want. **16** Wash, cleanse yourselves, remove the evil of your deeds from before My eyes, cease to do evil. **17** Learn to do good, seek justice, strengthen the robbed, perform justice for the orphan, plead the case of the widow. **18** Come now, let us debate, says the Lord. If your sins prove to be like crimson, they will become white as snow; if they prove to be as red as crimson dye, they shall become as wool.

Comment: Peace, so why was it instituted in the first place (Sacrificial System)?

Comment: It was instituted for atonement of unintentional sins. If a person commits an offence and is caught he has to pay back what he took and more.  Also sacrifices were made for other reason like thanks, happiness & good things that happened in their lives. Key is repentance  and turning away from sins.

Comment: So then going back to OP's question, "Why did God institute the Sacrificial system if prayers can atone for sins"?

Comment: For unintentional sins

Comment: And yet we do not make sacrifices for unintentional sins today.

Comment: If prayer can atone for intentional sins, can it not atone for unintentional sins?

Comment: @DoubleAA, When a person repents and brings an animal that is his possession he is expressing that he has "Sacrificed" something of value as a reminder that he should not repeat his sins. The intent of setting up the sacrificial system was to make sure there is a realization in the person to not go on sinning and assume that all they need to do is make a sin offering and they will be forgiven.

Comment: @TurkHill, Sacrifices are always on the alter in the temple. Since the temple is not there the sacrifices are not being made. But even if the temple was there repentance and  turning away from sin is key. Please see 1 kings 8:46. Solomon anticipated that someday the Israelites will not be in the land(no temple in the foreign land) to make sacrifices and hence he says they will turn to you and away from their sins and G-d will forgive them.

Comment: @Yeddu Yes, King Solomon said that. However, Rav Kook wrote that in the future we will bring grain instead of murdering animals. I think this is a better sacrifice.

Comment: @TurkHill Agree. ***Jeremiah 33:17*** For this is what the Lord says: ‘David will never fail to have a man to sit on the throne of Israel, 18 nor will the Levitical priests ever fail to have a man to stand before me continually to offer burnt offerings, to burn grain offerings and to present sacrifices.’”

Comment: @TurkHill Ezekiel 45:22 And the prince shall make on that day for himself and for all the people of Israel a bull for a sin-offering.

Comment: @Yeddu This could be a metaphor for something. Rav Kook seems to say that we will only offer food in the future.

Answer (score 1):

just to clarify, prayer did not ***replace*** the sacrificial system (קרבנות), we pray every day for the קרבנות to return (in שמו"ע by רצה וכו ולתפילתם שעה והשב את העבודה וכו), but since we unfortunately can't bring קרבנות we pray/believe that our prayers suffice, i.e. see medrash קרח פ' י"ח that states ונשלמה פרים שפתינו (הושע יד) אמרו ישראל רבש"ע בזמן שבהמ"ק קיים היינו מקריבים קרבן ומתכפר ועכשיו אין בידינו אלא תפלה. This includes -but is not at all limited to- the sacrifices for atonement (which was needed in ***addition*** to repentance).

It is interesting to note what is said from the חפץ חיים (I believe he wrote it in his introduction to אסיפת זקנים on קודשים) that we as long as we don't have the ביהמ"ק are kind of "lucky" in that if we sin unintentionally etc. we can get away "cheap" by praying/repenting, and we don't have to spend a few hundred dollars on an animal and travel to Jerusalem to sacrifice it.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I disagree. Prayer did repace the sacrificial system (or at least the sacrificial system with animals). Rav Kook wrote that in the future we will return to the sacrificial system but the sacrifice would be grain, fruit, intimate objects.

Answer (score 0):

The intended way of atonement is by sacrifices. However, it is not always possible to bring a sacrifice, since the sacrifices are dependent on the Temple. (This point is deserving of a question in itself to be properly explained and understood.) It was know to God from the beginning that there would be a time when sacrifices would be unavailable to people, so it was arranged from the beginning that one can also achieve atonement by other means, by prayer and fasting.

We find such an atonement already by Abraham [(Genesis 20:7)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.20.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he):

> וְעַתָּה הָשֵׁב אֵשֶׁת־הָאִישׁ כִּי־נָבִיא הוּא וְיִתְפַּלֵּל בַּעַדְךָ וֶחְיֵה וְאִם־אֵינְךָ מֵשִׁיב דַּע כִּי־מוֹת תָּמוּת אַתָּה וְכׇל־אֲשֶׁר־לָךְ׃
>
> Therefore, restore the man’s wife—since he is a prophet, he will intercede for you—to save your life. If you fail to restore her, know that you shall die, you and all that are yours.”

Also in [Joel(2:12-13)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Joel.2.12-13?lang=bi&lang2=he):

> וְגַם־עַתָּה נְאֻם־יְהֹוָה שֻׁבוּ עָדַי בְּכׇל־לְבַבְכֶם וּבְצוֹם וּבִבְכִי וּבְמִסְפֵּד׃
> וְקִרְעוּ לְבַבְכֶם וְאַל־בִּגְדֵיכֶם וְשׁוּבוּ אֶל־יְהֹוָה אֱלֹהֵיכֶם כִּי־חַנּוּן וְרַחוּם הוּא אֶרֶךְ אַפַּיִם וְרַב־חֶסֶד וְנִחָם עַל־הָרָעָה׃
>
> “Yet even now”—says the LORD— “Turn back to Me with all your hearts, And with fasting, weeping, and lamenting.” Rend your hearts Rather than your garments, And turn back to the LORD your God. For He is gracious and compassionate, Slow to anger, abounding in kindness, And renouncing punishment.

And many other sources.

Comment: Your first sentence, at least, is mistaken. The intended way of atonement is by sacrifices and repentance.

Comment: I hope anyone reading the question sees it as I did, that, supposedly, repentance and sacrifices were replaced with repentance and prayer. But good point.

Answer (score -5):

Rambam felt that G-d neither needs nor wants sacrifices. It is a concession to human nature. He says that this is also the view of the prophets.[1]

G-d declares: “To what purpose is the multitude of your sacrifices unto me? says the Lord” (Isaiah 1:11). Jeremiah 7:22–23 says, “For I (G-d) spoke not unto your fathers nor commanded them in the day that I brought them out of the land of Egypt concerning burnt offerings or sacrifice. But this thing I commanded them, saying, ‘Obey My voice.’”

We see from here that G-d neither needs nor wants sacrifices, and only "allowed" them as a concession to human needs.

The first rabbis to say that prayer has replaced the sacrificial system was around 70 CE when the temple was destroyed. The ancient rabbis felt that sacrifices were no longer necessary. It is primitive and backwards. Rabban Yohanan ben Zakkai correctly understood that Temple-oriented Judaism, along with its animal sacrifices, had ceased to exist when the Temple was destroyed. He thereby established “Rabbinic Judaism,” which was people-oriented, centered around the synagogue instead of the Temple, and prayers instead of sacrifices.

Rabbi Dr. Binyamin Lau in his book called “The Sages,” writes that Rabban Yohanan ben Zakkai “heralded a radical innovation in the religious life of Jews, affirming the equivalent value of religious life without sacrifices.” In other words, it simply means that ben Zakkai is saying that we don’t need sacrifices.

[1] See Guide of the Perplexed 3:32.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but the final paragraph is not necessary and should be removed

Comment: Like the commenter above, I agree the last paragraph should be removed (it is by far the most egregious paragraph, and borderline heretical). But I also think the second, third, and fourth paragraph should be removed for being just plain wrong. And I suspect the first and fifth paragraphs could be removed as well.

Comment: @bondonk Thank you for your suggeston. I will remove it.

Comment: @Salmononius2 I removed the last paragraph, however, the rest of the answer answered the question of when, why, and who stopped sacrifices. It is good to have discussions. You may be right. But I think that Rambam was against sacrifices.

Comment: I never said it was off topic, just that it was wrong. You did answer the question asked, you just gave an answer that is wrong and bad.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Your entitled to your opinion. Again, you may be right but I think my answer is correct. It is certainly not "bab."

Comment: I would recommend reading that Rambam.

Comment: @bondonk Rambam felt strongly that G-d neither needs nor wants sacrifices. Why solve unnecessary violence (sin) with more unnecessary violence (murdering animals)?

Comment: You haven't given any evidence that human nature is different than it ever was.

Comment: @Heshy Rambam wrote that people improve (slowly as time progresses) Thereby, prayer replaced the sacrifices. Rav Kook wrote that we will continue sacrifices in the future, however, this will be more mature. We will use grain and fruit instead of murdering animals. The original sacrificial system was a concession to human nature. What more proof do you need that human nature has progressed since the temple was destroyed (when we repent with prayer)?

Comment: To understand why your point in paragraphs two and three are false takes just a modicum of basic reading comprehension. The prophets are not claiming that one is not supposed to keep the laws of sacrifices. They are very clearly lamenting how people were overall not living proper lives while still following the technical rituals (i.e. following the letter of the law, but not the spirit). The prophets are exhorting the people to live proper spiritual lives, they were by no means telling people to stop following the technical rituals.

Comment: 1/2 As an example, imagine a case where someone is brought before a judge. The judge says "You're accused of running every red light and stop sign in town, sideswiped a dozen cars, hit seven pedestrians, and crashed your car into the post office while driving drink. What do you plead?" The defendant responds "But I was wearing a seat belt, your honor!" The judge replies "I don't care about whether you were wearing a seat belt!"

Comment: 2/2 Now, would you claim that the judge believes that one shouldn't wear a seat belt? Or if you asked him whether there were still seat belt laws, he would say "no, they're no longer relevant"? Of course not! But in the context of that case, seat belt laws are irrelevant and in some sense almost a distraction. That's what the prophets are saying, G-D wants people to live a complete spiritual life. Does He also want the technical laws to be followed? Of course, but that's an irrelevant discussion related to what the prophets are trying to teach.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Thank you for your comments but I believe the analogy fails. The prophets are saying that G-d prefers moral action to sacrifices. This makes sense. Why should a Just, Compassionate, and Merciful G-d require humans to disturb the moral sensitivity of the world by murdering animals when prayer is suitable for repentance?

Comment: There's that 'borderline heretical' philosophy again! You are essentially saying "I believe X to be true/moral/sensible/just, and since I am correct that X is true/moral/sensible/just, G-d must believe that too". Maybe, just maybe, you're wrong, and G-d is right, even if you don't like it?

Comment: @Salmononius2 the laws of morality work the same way from the beginning to the end. In other words, what is immoral now was never morally right at any time, in the past or future. Maybe you are wrong and the Rambam is right when he said that G-d neither needs nor wants sacrifices. It is not borderline heretical at all for G-d to demand justice. G-d declares: “For I spoke not unto your fathers nor commanded them in the day that I brought them out of the land of Egypt concerning burnt offerings or sacrifice. But this thing I commanded them, saying, ‘Obey My voice.’”

Comment: Show me chapter and verse where the Passuk, Rambam, or any other authority writes that it is immoral to offer animal sacrifices. Even if we concede that the verse is saying "I no longer want you to offer animal sacrifices" (which is not at all the simple, logical reading of the verse), nowhere does it append "because animal sacrifice is immoral". That is your own addition, and without any support, it is the ramblings of a random internet user (much like my comments, but at least on average my ramblings have the consensus of other random internet users).

Comment: @Salmononius2 Would you murder your pet as a sacrifice? Wouldn't this be immoral? Why did Rav Kook say we will sacrifice plant food instead? Didn't he feel that animal sacrifices were primitive and backwards? Why would a just, compassionate and merciful G-d desire the slaughter of animals to forgive humans when prayer is more than sufficiant? Rambam agreed. He felt that G-d does not need or want sacrifices.

Comment: So in short, no, you do not have any sources to back your claims and at best have a weak 'appeal to emotion' argument to twist the Rambam's words into agreeing with you?

Comment: @Salmononius2 Rabbi Chaim Hirschensohn wrote of Noah sacrificing to G-d after the flood: “It is not farfetched to interpret this verse that G-d laughed and had pity on the simplicity of man who thinks he can thank Him by offering a burnt animal or bird and destroy them at a time when there are so few of them in the world, and think he is doing what is right. This indicates that the imagination of man’s heart is evil from his youth in that even a gift to G-d is given with such **cruelty**.…

Comment: ... How is it possible that this would please God?” In essence, Rabbi Hirschensohn agrees with Rambam’s understanding of sacrifices as concessions to human nature.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Also, Rabbi Chaim Hirschensohn felt that animal sacrifices would not return in the future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126972/discussion-between-salmononius2-and-turk-hill).

Comment: The answer is partly correct, as the Rambam certainly believes that sacrifices were a concession. However, there is no basis for saying that the concession is not necessary today. See https://torahclarity.blogspot.com/2016/09/he-has-no-physical-form.html

Comment: @tcdw I agree with you. Rambam felt it was a concession. Rav kook seems to say that we will offer food as future sacrifices. Thank you for your comment.